# RouteBuilder Camel

Tags: java, camel

помогите разобраться в маршрутах camel плиз. Читаю читаю и не понимаю, понимаю как через XML, но мне надо сделать через Java класс, и без Spring. Нужно из файла properties составить строку запроса, то есть endpoint. и далее ее выполнить(например http://server:22000/api/token?login=login&pass=pass)

В ответ должен прийти токен.
Вот мой класс, все бралось из доки, но мне не ясно это from("direct:start"), что за direct:start, или я должен здесь что-то другое прописать? Например как раз получение адреса? Это я уже просто эксперементирую.

```
public class PrepareOapiForAuthTokenRoute extends RouteBuilder {

final String applicationProperties = "application.properties";

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:start").process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("2222");
        }
    });

}

public String gerUrl() throws IOException {
    Properties applicationProps = new PropUtils().readProperties(applicationProperties);
    String user = (String)applicationProps.get("oapi.user");
    String url = (String)applicationProps.get("oapi.url");
    String pass = (String)applicationProps.get("oapi.password");
    String fullUrl = url + "?login=" + user + "&password=" + pass;
    System.out.println(fullUrl);
    return fullUrl;
}
}
```

Делаю тест вот так, но ничего мне не выходит,даже просто строку, что выполнилось все

```
public class PaysRouteBuilderTest {

final private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PaysRouteBuilderTest.class);


@Test
public void test() {
    RouteBuilder builder = new PrepareOapiForAuthTokenRoute();
    try {
        builder.configure();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception: ",e);
    }

}
}
```

Сделал вот такой тест, и даже вроде работает и выстраивает строку, но сам процессор не работает, то есть сообщение не выводит

```
public class PaysRouteBuilderTest extends CamelTestSupport {

final private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PaysRouteBuilderTest.class);
final String applicationProperties = "application.properties";


@Test(timeout = 10000)
public void testMethod() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(5000); // Нужно, чтобы Camel успел обработать файлы, до завершения теста
}

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("direct:start")
                    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
                    .to("http:" + gerUrl()).process(new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            //HttpServletResponse response = exchange.getOut().getBody(HttpServletResponse.class);
                            System.out.println("ghjhh");
                        }
                    });
        }
    };
}

public String gerUrl() {
    Properties applicationProps = null;
    try {
        applicationProps = new PropUtils().readProperties(applicationProperties);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String user = (String)applicationProps.get("oapi.user");
    String url = (String)applicationProps.get("oapi.url");
    String pass = (String)applicationProps.get("oapi.password");
    String fullUrl = url + "?login=" + user + "&password=" + pass;
    return fullUrl;
}
}
```

Comment: Понял вот что, наверно from("direct:start") Start Это как раз бин, а метод чтобы указать, то надо писать from("direct:" + getUrl())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понятно из вопроса в каком контексте должен запускаться маршрут (`route`), поэтому будем считать, что по шедулеру.

**Что такое apache camel direct?**

[Apache camel direct](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html) - это точка некоего "ручного" входа в маршрут.

> URI format
>
> direct:someName[?options]
>
> Where someName can be any string that uniquely identifies the endpoint.

Где, `someName` - это любое строковое название данной точки.

**В итоге, маршрут (`route`), видимо, должен быть такой:**

1. Запустить маршрут, например по таймеру ([apache camel timer](http://camel.apache.org/timer.html))
2. Сформировать/переопределить http-url в бине/процессоре или в самом маршруте (route) через `Message Headers` в [apache camel http](http://camel.apache.org/http.html)
3. Вызвать `http`, например через `http`-компоненту ([apache camel http](http://camel.apache.org/http.html))

**Дополняю ответ примером `Predicate`:**

```
private Predicate predicateExample() {
    return new Predicate() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
            return true; //здесь реализуется какая-то логика
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Убрав "direct:start", и поставив тайминг, у меня получилось вызвать работу процессора. Спасибо, теперь немного понятно как  и что, буду дальше разбирать

Comment: Да, понимая особого нет, пока учусь :) мне вот не ясно direct:example, вот example, это что? имя бина? просто в доке это все указано, а что это, нет объяснения

Comment: Дополнил ответ описанием URI-формата для direct. То есть для "direct:example", "example" - это просто любое название точки входа в маршрут. Можно использовать для входа в данный маршрут именно в данную точку direct:example из какого-то другого маршрута. Например так: to("direct:example");

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Михаил, может вы мне еще подскажете, я делаю маршрут на Java DSL. Спринга нет, сейчас у меня есть переменная private SsoTokenHolder ssoTokenHolder = new SsoTokenHolder(); мне в маршруте в компоненте when надо ее проверить ssoTokenHolder.getTokenRecord() != null, то есть вызвать метод гет и не равен ли он null. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать без бина? я уже много перепробывал, как Предикат не выходит создать и так не работает .when().simple("${ssoTokenHolder.getTokenRecord()} != null") :(

Comment: Я добавил в ответе пример предиката. Его можно использовать в when()

Comment: Большое спасибо, я почти так же сделал, значит в правильную сторону капал